# Using chi-square test for statistics with multiple options in one variable

Tags: probability, statistics

i think that this is more mathematical question, i am doing some statistics on survey. There is questions with multiple choices, so for example, if there are 4 choices, i can pick 1st ,2nd and 4th. Started to create table about how males and females have answered it . And i realized, that 1 male/female can have multiple answers/values for one question . Continuing example, lets say i have 5 males , they all together have chosen 2 times 1st answer, 3 times 2nd answer and 5 times 4th. It gives me numeric value of 2+3+5 = 10, like there would be 10 participants.

How i should approach this?  Or there is different method for that case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since multiple choices are possible for a single variable, this is equivalent to having a binary variable for each possible value for each possible variable. So then you'll get a $2 \times 2 \times N$ table, where one dimension is gender and one dimension is chosen/ not chosen and the last dimension is all the possible values for the variables. You want to test for independence between the first $2 \times N$ table (for male) from the second $2 \times N$ table (for female). Since every value for every variable is set to true or false, this boils down to testing for independence between two $1 \times N$ tables. This is a well known problem, a generalization of Fischer's exact test.